# Creating usage log report from exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to get user information from exchange server 2007?

I'm looking particularly for the *display name, total inbox items, unread emails, unread emails 7 days or older and out of office status* for all users.

I have found some application available online but was wondering if there is some way to do the same reading exchanges logs using C# or a log reader of some sort.

I've also found WebDav and exchange SDK, but felt I couldn't get all the needed information with that.

If I'm wrong could someone show me a sample code of how it could be done? Preferably in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your information can be obtained by the [Get-MailboxFolderStatistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb124612.aspx) cmdlet. For other information you'll have to use EWS or, better yet, the EWS Managed API.

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx